# Array sorting using presorted ranking

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, ranking, decision-tree

I'm building a decision tree algorithm. The sorting is very expensive in this algorithm because for every split I need to sort each column. So at the beginning - even before tree construction I'm presorting variables - I'm creating a matrix so for each column in the matrix I save its ranking. Then when I want to sort the variable in some split I don't actually sort it but use the presorted ranking array. The problem is that I don't know how to do it in a space efficient manner.

A naive solution of this is below. This is only for 1 variabe (v) and 1 split (split_ind).

```python
import numpy as np

v = np.array([60,70,50,10,20,0,90,80,30,40])
sortperm = v.argsort()                            #1 sortperm = array([5, 3, 4, 8, 9, 2, 0, 1, 7, 6]) 
rankperm = sortperm.argsort()                     #2 rankperm = array([6, 7, 5, 1, 2, 0, 9, 8, 3, 4])

split_ind = np.array([3,6,4,8,9])                 # this is my split (random)

# split v and sortperm 
v_split = v[split_ind]                            # v_split        = array([10, 90, 20, 30, 40])
rankperm_split = rankperm[split_ind]              # rankperm_split = array([1, 9, 2, 3, 4])

vsorted_dummy = np.ones(10)*-1                    #3 allocate "empty" array[N]
vsorted_dummy[rankperm_split] = v_split
vsorted = vsorted_dummy[vsorted_dummy!=-1]        # vsorted = array([ 10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  90.])
```

Basically I have 2 questions:

1. Is double sorting necessary to create ranking array? (#1 and #2)
2. In the line #3 I'm allocating `array[N]`. This is very inefficent in terms of space because even if split size n << N I have to allocate whole array. The problem here is how to calculate `rankperm_split`. In the example original `rankperm_split = [1,9,2,3,4]` while it should be really `[1,5,2,3,4]`. This problem can be reformulated so that I want to create a "dense" integer array that has maximum gap of 1 and it keeps the ranking of the array intact.

UPDATE

I think that second point is the key here. This problem can be redefined as

`A[N]` - array of size N
`B[N]` - array of size N

I want to transform array A to array B so that:

1. Ranking of the elements stays the same (for each pair i,j if `A[i] < A[j]` then `B[i] < B[j]`
2. Array B has only elements from 1 to N where each element is unique.

A few examples of this transformation:

- [3,4,5] => [1,2,3]
- [30,40,50] => [1,2,3]
- [30,50,40] => [1,3,2]
- [3,4,50] => [1,2,3]

A naive implementation (with sorting) can be defined like this (in Python)

```python
def remap(a):
    a_ = sorted(a)
    b = [a_.index(e)+1 for e in a]
    return b
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 sorts?  How is the second sort influenced by the first?

Comment: First argsort creates a sorting permutation so that sorted(A) = A[argsort(A)]. Second argsort creates ranking of A so that min(A) has ranking 1 and max(A) has ranking N (where N is size(A)) and each element of ranking defines position in the sorted(A). Maybe there's better way to create ranking but I don't know it.